# Observable causes code to be called three times

Tags: angular

I'm making use of a few observables in my code to retrieve data from a database. However within one of my observable subscriptions there is another nested subscription, when the first subscription is called it causes the code within the second subscription to be called three times.

This doesn't make any sense however as the first subscription only receives a single object, therefore the code inside of it's next() function should only be called once. But if I look within my console my logs are printed out three separate times.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.displayForm = false;

    this.settingsService.getOrganisations().subscribe( (res: AdminOrganisation[]) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.organisations = res;
      this.modalRef = this.openSelectOrganisationsModal();
      console.log(this.modalRef);
      this.modalRef.componentInstance.selectedOrganisation.subscribe(serial => {
        this.serial = serial;
        this.buildSettingsForm(this.serial)
      });
    });

buildSettingsForm(serial: string) {
    this.ipRangeFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
        {
          ipRanges: this.formBuilder.array([])

        }
    );

    this.numArrayElements = this.ipRangeFormArray.length;

    this.ipRangeFormArray.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
      this.numArrayElements = this.ipRangeFormArray.length;

      if (this.numArrayElements === 0) {
        this.ipRestrictionEnabled = false;
      }
    });

    console.log(this.ipRangeFormArray);
    console.log('numArrayElements: ' + this.numArrayElements);

    this.toggleDisplayForm();

  }
```

Comment: Does it always gets called three time??

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems with the code, firstly you have nested subscribe calls, which is considered bad practice, as it makes code difficult to follow, Instead is pipe with MergeMap.

Your actual problem is likely that you do not unsubscribe from you subscriptions, every time your components gets initialized you get new subscription. you need to unsubscribe on NgOnDestroy.

Comment: How exactly can I use pipe and mergemap to make this code better?

Comment: Look on the RxJs [Website](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators) for Information how Operators work. Maybe this [side](https://rxmarbles.com/#mergeMap) could also help

Comment: @LukasS I've read the docs. I really don't understand how combining these two observables will help my situation?

Answer (score 0):

I create a new Answer because this text will be longer.

With mergeMap you get a function where you can work with the emitted value from the observable and then you can return a different Observable wich you than can later subscribe.

In your case I think this should work:

```
this.settingsService.getOrganisations().pipe(mergeMap((res: AdminOrganisation[]) => {
    console.log(res);
    this.organisations = res;
    this.modalRef = this.openSelectOrganisationsModal();
    console.log(this.modalRef);

    return modalRef;

  })).subscribe(serial => {
    this.serial = serial;
    this.buildSettingsForm(this.serial)
  });
```